# Sanic server on App Engine: RuntimeError: SPF processing a request before App server is started

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, runtime-error, sanic

Newbie to App Engine here; sorry if I'm missing something obvious, but I can't find this error written about anywhere online. If you [search for it on google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22SPF%20processing%20a%20request%20before%20App%20server%20is%20started.%22&oq=%22SPF%20processing%20a%20request%20before%20App%20server%20is%20started.%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.1913j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), this post is literally the only result.

I am using the Sanic framework to create an API on Google App Engine. Some lightweight machine learning tasks are done on the server, so I'm using a slightly beefed-up instance class with 8 workers and more memory. I'm also using Python 3.8 and using Sanic's built-in server (although the *exact same error* happened while using gunicorn as a reverse proxy). Here's my `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: python38
instance_class: F4_1G
entrypoint: sanic main.app --port=$PORT --workers=8
```

It's hard to pinpoint the exact conditions under which the following error happens, but I've observed it *every time* on the first request after a deploy, if it's been a while between requests, or directly after one of my ML-related requests that takes a couple of minutes to resolve.

Every time the error is thrown, the server will think for a while, then return nothing. The following logs correspond to it (note that the most recent logs are at the top and I added newlines to highlight the error stack trace):

```
[2020-07-23 18:19:18 +0000] [28] [INFO] Starting worker [28]
[2020-07-23 18:19:18 +0000] [27] [INFO] Starting worker [27]
[2020-07-23 18:19:17 +0000] [26] [INFO] Starting worker [26]
[2020-07-23 18:19:17 +0000] [25] [INFO] Starting worker [25]
[2020-07-23 18:19:16 +0000] [24] [INFO] Starting worker [24]
Error detected in default version 20200723t140716
[2020-07-23 18:19:16 +0000] [23] [INFO] Starting worker [23]
[2020-07-23 18:19:16 +0000] [20] [INFO] Starting worker [20]
This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application.
[2020-07-23 18:19:16 +0000] [22] [INFO] Starting worker [22]

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/sanic/app.py", line 906, in handle_request
response = await self._run_request_middleware(
File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/spf/framework.py", line 611, in _run_request_middleware_19_12
raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: SPF processing a request before App server is started.

[2020-07-23 18:19:16 +0000] [20] [ERROR] Exception occurred while handling uri: '[URL omitted]'
[start] 2020/07/23 18:19:15.489374 Wait successful. Subject:"nginx" Address:127.0.0.1:8080 
[start] 2020/07/23 18:19:15.262144 Waiting for network connection open. Subject:"nginx" 
[start] 2020/07/23 18:19:15.255168 Starting nginx
[start] 2020/07/23 18:19:15.254848 Wait successful. Subject:"app/valid" Address:127.0.0.1:8081
[2020-07-23 18:19:15 +0000] [10] [INFO] Goin' Fast @ http://127.0.0.1:8081
```

What is going on here? Why could this error be happening?

Comment: UPDATE: I've switched over to Flask for this project, which does not have the issue. Would still love to hear peoples' ideas for the cause of this error, to maybe help some future devs :)

Comment: From the message "This request caused a new process to be started for your application, and thus caused your application code to be loaded for the first time. This request may thus take longer and use more CPU than a typical request for your application" it appears that you were encountering issues related to Loading Request [1] which resulted following error "RuntimeError: SPF processing a request before App server is started". The document [1] included some best practices for Loading Requests. [1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed#loading_requests

Comment: For future if you think any issue that has happened are technical in nature which you can report by creating a Public Issue using the right component as listed here [1] and one of the Google Cloud Support Agent will assist you. It is advised in case you need to share any Project specific information please select the private component during creation on the Public Issue so that your information are not visible to the Public.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list

Comment: It is related to whatever plugin you were using, not Sanic itself.